# Hit Ctrl+C during Enthought Canopy Installation - Now Seg Faults

Tags: python, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, enthought

So I ran the install script on a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit installation, and then ran

```
~Canopy/canopy
```

for the first time to set it up, which threw the following error but proceeded to run anyway:

```
QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.
```

Being the forgetful person that I am, having come from Windows recently, I highlighted the text of the error message and hit Ctrl+C while Canopy was still performing its first time setup routine. Canopy quit in the middle of setting itself up, and when I try to run Canopy I get:

```
QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried just running the install script again, then running it after deleting the Canopy directory, and I still get the above two lines.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi Zach, Canopy on Linux is still in beta; our Linux dev team will have a look at this.

Comment: No problem, let me know if there is a log somewhere that I can send you.

Answer (score 0):

Canopy does its first time setup in `~/Enthought` directory, you can delete that and try again.